# show and hide iframes with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a webpage with 2 iframes, 1 underneath the other. I would like both iframes hidden when a user first clicks on the webpage. There will be 2 buttons, 1 above each iframe and the user must click on the button to show/hide the iframe

Here is what I tired(jQuery function) but it wont seem to work when I preview in chrome from expression web

jsfiddle.net/darego/Z62P7/2/

Comment: Posting code is better than not doing so, but you might want to consider isolating the code to show just the problem area if you can, or at least tell people exactly where the problem is.

Comment: @Joonas Well the jQuery function does not seem to toggle show/hide the iframes so I think I did something wrong with the javascript in the <head> section. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to call the function after the document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    hideToggle(".button1", ".iframe1");
    hideToggle(".button2", ".iframe2");
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. i have only today started looking at javascript/jQuery so forgive me but could you please tell me where in the HTML to put them lives of code? :) thanks

Comment: @Craig Just replace the code lines where you are calling `hideToggle(x, y)` with the above code.

Comment: @axel.michel thanks a lot also! i don't have 15 rep to up vote your answer unfortunately! take care

Answer (score 1):

Just placing it in document ready will not be enough.
You can make your function MUCH easier.

```
function hideToggle(elem) {
    $(elem).toggle();
}
```

This means: If the element is visible > hide it, if it is hidden > show it.

But for your initializing (hide both divs) i would recommend doing it by css.

```
iframe {
     display:none;
}
```

Also you need to setup click handlers for the buttons. If you need help on this write me a comment or edit your question please.